# Real life SMACH examples?

Tags: smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have run through most of the [SMACH tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/smach/Tutorials) and I was hoping to find at least one example where SMACH is used on a real robot.  For example, was SMACH used for the PR2 marathon tests?  Or the "beer me" demo?  If so, is the source code available somewhere?  Any other examples would be welcome too.

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61105/real-life-smach-examples?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure about marathons -- but the [pr2_plugs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_plugs) application used SMACH

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-04-19**:
Thanks Fergs--this is great.